# Discord.js says "message is empty" but console.log shows data

Tags: javascript, discord.js, google-sheets-api

I'm currently working on a project that sends the information of my google-spreadsheets to a discord channel. So, I have some questions:

**1)** The final data (value), when I try to `console.log(value)`, it worked!

So that means it does get the data from google-spreadsheets and set it to (value).

But when I try to do `msg.channel.send(value)`, it responds to me with a crash and says can't send an empty message which makes me confused, why?

And therefore I can't send this value to my discord channel.

---

**2)**  My final data (value) as shown at the bottom of my code, is actually an array like this:

```
{ values: [ [A] , [B] , [C] , [D] , ... ] }
```

And I don't know how to change them into `A,B,C,D` form.
Does anyone know how to convert them?

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
async function google_sheet_get() {
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: "./google_sheets/Google_credentials.json",
        scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    })
    
    const client = await auth.getClient()
    const googleSheets = google.sheets({version: "v4", auth: client})
    const spreadsheetId = "My Sheet ID"
    const getRows = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth,
        spreadsheetId,
        majorDimension: "ROWS",
        range: "'Day1'!B1:F24"
    })
    return getRows.data
}

client.on('messageCreate', msg=> {
    if(msg.content.startsWith(settings.prefix+'ttes')||
    msg.content.startsWith(settings.prefix2+'ttes')) {
        sheet.get().then( value => msg.channel.send(value))
        msg.channel.send("Command ttes success.")
    }
})
```

Really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `value` is not a string, when you look at [channel.send()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), it accepts either string, "MessagePayload" object or "MessageOptions" object, so if the `value` is an object it tries to interpret it as either one of those and it fails because the required properties aren't there.

Try converting it to string before sending it, like: `` msg.channel.send(`${value}`) `` or `msg.channel.send(value.toString()`.

---

And as for the second part of the question you might want to take a look at [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
.

Comment: Thank you for your help! but I just found out the answer! For first I have to use `require('util').insepct`.
And for the second I'll need to use `Array.flat` and `Array.value `at the same time!
Still appericate your support!

Comment: Can you provide your solution as an answer? Maybe other members of the StackOverflow community are facing the same problem and your answer might be helpful to them.  [Answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)